# rearranging a list of dictionaries to make columns in a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that I need to transform into a dataframe.  What specifically needs to happen is the value of the 2nd key in each dictionary within the list should become the column header, while the value of the 1st key within the list of dictionaries should be the value for each column.

```
test_list = [{"key" : 1, "code" : "update"}, 
             {"key" : 2, "code" : "birthday"}, 
             {"key" : 3, "code" : "today"}]
```

The data frame output should look something like this:

df example output:

```
update birthday today
1      2        3
```

I thought about making two lists and zipping them into a new dictionary but was not sure if that was the best approach.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this, maybe share some data? Is there only going to be a single row?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
s = pd.DataFrame(test_list).set_index('code').T
Out[7]: 
code  update  birthday  today
key        1         2      3
```